# PHP YouTube API not working on my hosting

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api, php-curl

I am getting mp4 URL from YouTube API with PHP. But it works on local server and not on hosting.

Here is a screenshot of the error I got:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4voYr.jpg)

I am getting mp4 URL of video from YouTube API with PHP. I am using these codes:

```
<?php

function getVideoInfo($video_id){

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player?key=[key]');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{  "context": {    "client": {      "hl": "en",      "clientName": "WEB",      "clientVersion": "2.20210721.00.00",      "clientFormFactor": "UNKNOWN_FORM_FACTOR",   "clientScreen": "WATCH",      "mainAppWebInfo": {        "graftUrl": "/watch?v='.$video_id.'",           }    },    "user": {      "lockedSafetyMode": false    },    "request": {      "useSsl": true,      "internalExperimentFlags": [],      "consistencyTokenJars": []    }  },  "videoId": "'.$video_id.'",  "playbackContext": {    "contentPlaybackContext": {        "vis": 0,      "splay": false,      "autoCaptionsDefaultOn": false,      "autonavState": "STATE_NONE",      "html5Preference": "HTML5_PREF_WANTS",      "lactMilliseconds": "-1"    }  },  "racyCheckOk": false,  "contentCheckOk": true}');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $headers = array();

    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {

        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);

    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

}

print_r(getVideoInfo("[video_id]"));
```

There is no problem running on local server. I am able to get the mp4 URL of the video. But when I upload the files to the hosting and run it, the URL from the API tells me "This content isn't available." fetches an mp4 file containing the text. How can I solve this? Both are the same code, but what could be the reason why it works on local server and not on hosting?

Comment: Where is the API key stored locally? It's sent with the request ('https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player?key=[key]'). The key must be available on the remote machine too.

Comment: fsck the youtube api, use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)